# CoreData crashing with fetched property in child managed object context

Tags: ios, core-data

I have what I thought was pretty simple. There is a parent moc that is on a private queue, and a child moc that is on the main queue. The schema contains the following fetched property predicate in an entity:

```
    parentuuid == $FETCH_SOURCE.uuid
```

When I go to fetch this from within the entity's class (in the child moc on the main thread), I get an exception:

```
    *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', 
    reason: '[<_NSObjectID_48_2 0x12fafb10> valueForUndefinedKey:]: 
    this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key uuid.'
```

I can tell basically what's going on here. For some reason CoreData has fetched an object id instead of an object, and it's trying to run the predicate on that. I don't know why that's occurring.

I've traced this to the parent/child managed object context. If I go back to just using one managed object context on the main thread, this crash stops.

Has anyone seen this before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Contacted Apple and this is fixed in a future version of iOS.

Comment: Uh, so I'm seeing this in iOS 7.0.2... but future version do you mean 7.1 or should this already be fixed?

Comment: It was fixed in a 7.0.0 beta. Hopefully they didn't break it again!

Comment: I'm seeing this same problem in iOS 7.1, and other people seem to be reporting the same thing on the Apple Developer forums. I've filed bug #16697979.